# Testing file upload in lumen 5.5

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, lumen

I'm using Lumen 5.5, and I wrote simple app that upload files.

I wrote test like this (following [this](https://laravel-news.com/testing-file-uploads-with-laravel) tutorial)

```
<?php

class UploadImageTest extends TestCase
{

    Use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function testUploadingImageSuccessfully()
    {
        $this->json('POST', '/images', [
            'image' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('image.jpg')
        ])->assertResponseOk()
    }

}
```

problem is that in my controller, `$request->file('image')` returns null.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UploadController extends Controller
{

    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->file('image')) { // always return null
            return "File is uploaded!";
        }

        return "File is not uploaded!";
    }

}
```

I checked other questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408134/how-to-test-file-upload-in-laravel-5-2)) and tried given solutions with no luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across this question while searching for the answer to the same problem and wasn't sure it was related, so I posed one relevant to my use case. [(Here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46485894/lumen-5-5-json-api-file-upload-test-breaks-with-uploadedfile)

The solution is simple: UploadedFile::fake() doesn't work with JSON, as it fakes a file upload with an XmlHttpRequest (as far as I can tell). You must therefore change your test from this:

```
public function testUploadingImageSuccessfully()
{
    $this->json('POST', '/images', [
        'image' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('image.jpg')
    ])->assertResponseOk()
}
```

to this:

```
public function testUploadingImageSuccessfully()
{
    $this->call('POST', '/images', [
        'image' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('image.jpg')
    ])->assertResponseOk()
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Please note that passing file argument in the second argument of `call()` method does not work. Since the second argument is the payload data.

If you pass it as the data, when you use the command on the backend like this:

```php
if($request->hasFile('my_file')) {
    // Do some logic here
}
```

`$request->hasFile()` will always return false.

You need to pass fake file upload in the 5th argument to make this works.

Here is the method signature of `call`

```php
call($method, $uri, $parameters = [], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is working for me. just simple. this can submit file upload.

1.condition without authentication

`5*1000` is file size (in KB). so i made a test with `5 MB` file.

```
use Faker\Factory as Faker;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

class SampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testItCanCreateUser()
    {
        $faker = Faker::create();
        $files = [
            'file' => UploadedFile::fake()->create('file.jpg', 5*1000)
        ];
        $response = $this->call('POST', '/chunk', [], [], $files);
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

2.condition with authentication (logged in user)

```
use Faker\Factory as Faker;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

class SampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testItCanUpdateProfileUser()
    {
        $faker = Faker::create();
        $files = [
            'file' => UploadedFile::fake()->create('file.jpg', 5*1000)
        ];

        $headers = [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'your-jwt-token'
        ];
        $servers = [];
        foreach ($headers as $k => $header) {
            $servers["HTTP_" . $k] = $header;
        }

        $response = $this->call('POST', '/chunk', [], [], $files, $servers);
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

you need to add `HTTP_` on every request header. i'm not sure why. but it will work.