# Laravel phpunit test maatwebsite/excel import

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, maatwebsite-excel

I've created an maatwebsite/excel import routine and i would like to test it.

The maatwebsite/excel testing page does not provide me with any other information than to fake it.
But i need to upload my real excel-file, as i want to validate whether the data from the excel file was processed correctly.

Here's my upload input field and the corresponding button to hit the endpoint `/import`

```
<form action="/import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   <div class="form-group">
       <input type="file" class="form-control-file file-path" name="fileToUpload">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Import File</button>
</form>
```

on the controller side of view, the uploaded file will be processed and imported.

```
...

public function store(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
            'fileToUpload' => 'required|file|max:4096|mimes:xls,xlsx',
        ]);

        // start the import
        Excel::import(new SheetNavigator, request()->file('fileToUpload'));
...
```

The file that needs to be imported is located within my testing environment under:

```
/tests
  /files
    /myexcel.xlsx
```

```
public function test_user_can_import_file() {

        Excel::fake();

        $datafile = new UploadedFile(
            base_path('tests/files/myfile.xlsx'),
            'myfile.xlsx',
            'xlsx',
            13071,
            true);

        $res = $this->post('/import', [
            'fileToUpload' => $datafile
        ]);

        // asserting, that everything works..

    }
```

I need a test to verify that the upload was successful and that the import-routine was triggered.
I tried everything, from faking anything to using storages.

I appreciate any kind of help, thank you!

Chris

Comment: Would be useful to share what you've actually tried.

Comment: oh, that should be within my question, i'll update it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking the ideal way to do this is by mocking the `Excel` class and then checking if `import` has been called with the given file. Despite the fact that this seems to be a static call it's actually a [Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/facades) call so you can swap it out with a mock. In fact it seems to offer this functionality on its own:

```
public function testThatItImportsTheUploadedFile() {
    $file = UploadedFile::fake()->create('myexcel.xlsx');

    Excel::fake();

    $this->post('/import', [
        'fileToUpload' => $file
    ]);

    Excel::assertImported('myexcel.xlsx');

}
```

Note: This verifies that the endpoint works as expected given that the file is uploaded and `Excel::import` will work as expected.

If you want to test with your real file you can possibly create a new [`UploadedFile`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php) instance (linking the symfony base class since that's where the constructor is).

```
$file = new UploadedFile(
    base_path('tests/files/myfile.xlsx'),
    'myfile.xlsx',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    null,
    true
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to fake an excel sheet, and the import succeded. But i cant use my real file from my /files directory.

Comment: @jo-chris you can possibly create a new instance as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/36414073/487813 but I don't see any reason to do so. This is a unit test so you should only focus on the unit being tested, in this case the endpoint. I've updated my answer to show the "correct" way to instantiate this class